# integration in python: y(t,E)=-A+2A*Integral [g(t,tau)*f(Ea)]dEa

Tags: python, math, numerical-integration

I need to carry out the integral written in the figure:

[image]

I want to plot y(t,E) for a given value of E. In my code I get this message: "*divide by zero encountered in double_scalars*"

I don't understand in an integration process why would there a "divide by" come? What would be a better code to do this work?

My code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

def integrand(Ea,A,t,E,tau0,n,alpha,mu,sig):

    tau=tau0*np.exp(-np.power(E/Ea,alpha));
    g=1-np.exp(-np.power((t/tau),n));
    f=np.exp(-np.power(Ea - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)));

    return -A+2*A*g*f
#    


A=25;
t=1e-6;  #Calculating for one t value. For plotting, t would be an array.
E=1;
tau0=0.3*1e-6;
n=2;
alpha=5
mu=2;
sig=0.3;

Y = quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=(A,t,E,tau0,n,alpha,mu,sig))
print(Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can safely ignore the warning. The integral is probably diverging at some point and the warning you get tells that the number of iterations fell short in finding a converged solution. If you print the error (`y[1]`), you will see that it is quite small as compared to the absolute value of the integral (`y[0]`). The dependence of the integral with time can be computed as following

```
time = np.logspace(-8, -5, 100)
Ylist = []
for t in time:
    Y = quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=(A,t,E,tau0,n,alpha,mu,sig))
    Ylist.append(Y[0])

plt.semilogx(time, Ylist, '-kx')
plt.xlabel('Time (log)')
plt.ylabel(r'$y(t, E)$')
```

[image]